# Non-rotating film by XeLatex

Tags: xetex, media9

Non-rotating film by XeLatex

```
% XeLatex
    \documentclass[10pt]{report}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{media9}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \rotatebox{45}{\includemedia[addresource=cube.mp4,
    flashvars={source=cube.mp4&autoPlay=true &loop=true},passcontext 
    ]{\includegraphics[height=0.45\linewidth]{cubeposter}}{VPlayer9.swf}}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[upload Outpud](http://s2.picofile.com/d/8373170200/e898b3d1-3639-42b1-8eda-06551c77ce25/test.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean with "non-rotating"?

Comment: Picture of swing but not a film(cube.mp4)!

Comment: Which PDF viewer do you use? You will need Acrobar Reader.

Comment: Yes, not rotate film by xelatex. Correct by PdfLatex

Comment: 45-degree rotating film show

Comment: This is not possible. The video canvas cannot be rotated for playback in Acrobat Reader. This is independent from PDF creation, whether pdflatex or xelatex, it doesn't matter.